# Formtastic Collection Select Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

When using formtastic in my rails3 application, I can't get the dropdown menus to work. Instead they appear as a selection list.

My code looks like this:

```
<%= f.label :slas, "Service" %></td><td><%= f.input :slas, :collection => @slas %>
```

Is this something I need to change in the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that took some fiddling.

In order to get a single dropdown list, instead of the select box, I needed to do this:

```
<%= f.label :slas, "Service" %></td><td><%= f.input :slas, :as => :select, :multiple => false, :input_html => { :size => 1 }   %>
```

That was surprisingly hard...

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. `:as => :select` should have done the trick by itself.